# Rotate google map with vue2-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I want to turn the map 90 degrees. How can I do ? I use vue2-google-maps to create a map.

```
        <GmapMap
          id="map"
          :center="{lat:latitude, lng:longitude}"
          map-type-id="satellite"
          style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh"
          :zoom= zoom
          :tilt="rotate" // 45
          :options="{
            rotateControl: true,
            minZoom:5,
            maxZoom:20,
          }"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#Rotating45DegreeImagery) :

> Once your map is displaying `45°` imagery, you can orient the imagery
>   towards one of its cardinal directions by calling `setHeading()` on the
>   Map object, passing a number value expressed as degrees from North.

So, orient the imagery ( `heading` property) could be specified once `45°` imagery is set, here is an example for [`vue-google-maps`](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap 
       :center="center" 
      :zoom="zoom" 
      :mapTypeId="'satellite'"
      :tilt="titl"
      :heading="heading"
       ref="map">

    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 18,
      center: { lat: 45.518, lng: -122.672 },
      titl: 45,
      heading: 90
    };
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>
```